# How to generate calendar table for each calendar month and make it stop as of today in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am able to generate calendar table for each month, but it goes till the end of current month.

```
CalendarTest = 
SUMMARIZE(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR ("01-01-2018", TODAY()),
        "Month", EOMONTH([Date], - 1) + 1
              ),
              [Month],
              "Eomonth",EOMONTH([Month],0)
```

[image]

But the last value for Eomonth should be today's date. Not the end of the month.

Need it to be like that:

[image]

Comment: The `EOMONTH` function returns the **end** of the month which is 2/28/2019 in our case.

Comment: Yes. I need to return end of month for every month that is before today. But Eomonth columns has to be disrupt by today's date.

Comment: You need to calculate the `MIN(EOMONTH(..(), TODAY())`, but the function `EOMONTH` means the **E**nd **O**f **MONTH**, disregardent of the todays date (you can even use EOMONTH to calculate the end of upcoming months.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
CalendarTest = 
SUMMARIZE(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        CALENDAR ("01-01-2018", TODAY() ),
        "Month", EOMONTH ( [Date], - 1) + 1
    ),
    [Month],
    "Eomonth", MIN ( EOMONTH([Month],0), TODAY() )
)
```